# Deployment of keras layer UpSampling2D to tensorRT

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation, tensorrt

Kears/TensorFlow layer `UpSampling2D()` cannot be deployed to TensorRT (known behavior).

I am trying to find a solution by replacing the layer `UpSampling2D()` by other Keras layer with parallel behaviour.

Theoretically `Conv2DTranspose()` should do the work, by setting specific weights and fixing the weights of the layers in training.

I am looking for some help on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test run by replacing all the UpSampling 2D() with Conv2DTranspose() in my model and then converted it to UFF. (I only trained the model for 1 epoch to save time).
The converter then complained about DataFormatVecPermute instead.

```
Converting conv2d_transpose_1/conv2d_transpose-0-VecPermuteNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer as custom op: DataFormatVecPermute
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: DataFormatVecPermute yet.
```

And the parser in C++ couldn't parse this model successfully either.